# How to know the cause for assertion errors Python?

Tags: python, debugging, assertion

I am compiling a script for adding custom property in PDF files using PdfMerger() in PyPdf2. It worked fine for almost all the files except a few. And error occurs in some function inside the PdfMerge. I don't understand what exactly is causing this error or how to rectify it. Here is the entire program - not sure if giving a snippet would be helpful.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd 
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfMerger

df = pd.read_excel('S:\\USERS\\VINTON\\F001A - Item Master (Stock and Cost)- 270001.xlsx')
 
folder_path = "U:\\BMP" pdf_files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
 
for EachFile in pdf_files:
    search_value = EachFile
    print(EachFile)
    search_result = df[df['Item Number 02'] == search_value]
    # Find the corresponding value in the "Name" column of the same w
    if not search_result.empty:
        print("Found in JDE")
        Revision = search_result['Rev'].values[0]
        Description = search_result['Item Description 01'].values[0]
        FileName = "U:\\BMP\\" + search_value + ".pdf"
        # Get the file from BMP Folder
        file_in = open(FileName, 'rb')
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(file_in)
        if pdf_reader.is_encrypted:
            print("Encrypted")
            continue
        metadata = pdf_reader.metadata
        # Adding entire existing file to the new file created
        pdf_merger = PdfMerger()
        pdf_merger.append(file_in)
        pdf_merger.add_metadata({
            '/Revision': Revision,
            '/Description': Description
        })
        file_out = open("S:\\USERS\\VINTON\\BMP-Rev\\" + search_value ".pdf", 'wb')
        pdf_merger.write(file_out)
        file_in.close()
        file_out.close()
print("All Done!!")
```

I cannot figure out how to overcome assertion errors because the error is shown to have occurred in several layers below the simplified syntax.

Comment: What assertion error?  Do you get a stacktrace?  Usually the information you need to debug an exception is in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is "+" sign missing in this line before ".pdf"
file_out = open("S:\USERS\VINTON\BMP-Rev\" + search_value ".pdf", 'wb')

try this:

file_out = open("S:\USERS\VINTON\BMP-Rev\" + search_value + ".pdf", 'wb')

hope it works

Answer (score -1):

Use `try` and `except` statements when reading or merging `pdf` files to throw the exception messages if failed. It's always a good practice to throw errors and exceptions when working with files or memory for development purposes.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd 
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfMerger

df = pd.read_excel('S:\\USERS\\VINTON\\F001A - Item Master (Stock and Cost)- 270001.xlsx')
 
folder_path = "U:\\BMP" 
pdf_files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
 
for EachFile in pdf_files:
    search_value = EachFile
    print(EachFile)
    search_result = df[df['Item Number 02'] == search_value]
    # Find the corresponding value in the "Name" column of the same w
    if not search_result.empty:
        print("Found in JDE")
        Revision = search_result['Rev'].values[0]
        Description = search_result['Item Description 01'].values[0]
        FileName = "U:\\BMP\\" + search_value + ".pdf"
        # Get the file from BMP Folder
        file_in = open(FileName, 'rb')
        try:
            pdf_reader = PdfReader(file_in)
            if pdf_reader.is_encrypted:
                print("Encrypted")
                continue
            metadata = pdf_reader.metadata
            # Adding entire existing file to the new file created
            pdf_merger = PdfMerger()
            pdf_merger.append(file_in)
            pdf_merger.add_metadata({
                '/Revision': Revision,
                '/Description': Description
            })
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        file_out = open("S:\\USERS\\VINTON\\BMP-Rev\\" + search_value ".pdf", 'wb')
        pdf_merger.write(file_out)
        file_in.close()
        file_out.close()
print("All Done!!")
```

Comment: There's no `catch` keyword in Python.

Comment: Thanks *@pavel*, I edited that to `except` as the code was.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Someone else did. Not sure why they did it. If I were to guess, maybe there's too much code in the `try` statement. You always need to keep it to a minimum and only keep the part of code that throws exceptions.

Comment: I downvoted because this just ignores exceptions, and ignoring exceptions without first figuring out whether they reflect an actual bug in the code is a bad idea. Also, `pdf_merger` is likely to be undefined when the code tries to do `pdf_merger.write(file_out)`.

Comment: It throws an exception anyway, even though if it's `undefined`. *@pavel* you are absolutely right, it  can be separately used for opening files, writing to files, merging files etc.